# How to dynamically populate a RadioButtonList from the database within a Repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

This is the first time I have tried to dynamically populate a RadioButtonList from within a Repeater control. It is not going very well so far.

I am trying this code that I found here that supposedly worked for the guy who wrote it:

```
protected void fillRepeater_onitembound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        sql = "select PurchaseTypeID,PurchaseType from PurchaseType";
        object obj = null;
        ds = obj.openDataset(sql);
        ListItem li;

        RadioButtonList rbtl = (RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("radioatt");
        if (rbtl != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                li = new ListItem();
                li.Text = dt.Rows[i]["PurchaseType"].ToString();
                li.Value = dt.Rows[i]["PurchaseTypeID"].ToString();
                rbtl.Items.Add(li);
            }
        }
    }
}

<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="fillRepeater_onitembound">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <table style="width:100%;border: 1px solid black;">
         <tr>
          <td style="width:50%;border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;">
             Purchased:<asp:radiobuttonlist ID="rblPurchaseType" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" TextAlign="Right" style="display:inline;"></asp:radiobuttonlist></td>
              <td style="text-align:center;border: 1px solid black;">
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
     </table>  
     ...
     ...
     ...
  </asp:Repeater>
```

However, I am running into bugs:

**'object' does not contain a definition for 'openDataset' and no extension method 'openDataset' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?**

Any ideas what's wrong?

**UPDATE:**

```
    public DataTable LoadDataFromDatabase(string query)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
        {
            try
            {
                adapter.Fill(dt); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //handle error if needed
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }
    string myQuery = "SELECT PurchaseTypeID, PurchaseType FROM PurchaseType ORDER BY PurchaseType";
    string rbtl = Repeater2.FindControl("rblPurchaseType");
    rbtl.DataSource = LoadDataFromDatabase(myQuery);
    rbtl.DataTextField = "PurchaseType";
rbtl.DataValueField = "PurchaseTypeID";
rbtl.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is `obj`? Unless you cast it back to something that has an `openDataset` property this is never gonna work.

What I use is a simple method that returns a `DataTable` from a query and bind that to the `RadioButtonList`

```
public DataTable LoadDataFromDatabase(string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
    {
        try
        {
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle error if needed
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Now you can use this method to quickly and simple get your needed content from the database and bind it to whatever Control you need.

```
string myQuery = "SELECT PurchaseTypeID, PurchaseType FROM PurchaseType ORDER BY PurchaseType";

rbtl.DataSource = LoadDataFromDatabase(myQuery);
rbtl.DataTextField = "PurchaseType";
rbtl.DataValueField = "PurchaseTypeID";
rbtl.DataBind();
```

PS `rbtl` is always gonna be `null` in your case since the ID of the RadioButton in the aspx is `rblPurchaseType` and you use FindControl on `radioatt`, make sure these are the same.

Comment: thank you very much for your prompt response. Please help me further as I am not getting it right.

Running into all sorts of errors. I have updated code above.

Comment: It looks ok apart from the `Repeater2.FindControl`. If you use it inside the ItemDataBound event, you need to use e.Row.FindControl.